# Websocket will not function

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to use websockets to stream data from an API and I am receiving a attribute error. any help would be much appreciated!

```
import websocket

Stock_stream = 'wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream'

def on_open(ws)
#code

def on_message(ws, message)
#code

def on_close(ws)
#code

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(Stock_stream, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\hello\Alpaca_script.py", line 385, in <module>
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(Stock_stream, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'
```

WebSocketApp is also highlighted in yellow, it says, "cannot find reference 'WebSocketApp' in '**init**.py' "

Thank you

Comment: 'highlighted in yellow' is not a universal thing. What happens if you run the script? Can you give the stacktrace?

Comment: I understand that, sometimes it can be underlined in yellow and highlighted so i thought to make a point of which one it was. I am not too sure how to provide the stack trace, the code is fairly large.

Comment: When i run the code the traceback error shows: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/engli/PycharmProjects/hello/Alpaca_script.py", line 6, in <module>
    import calculatedTime4Real
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\hello\calculatedTime4Real.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Alpaca_script import *
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\hello\Alpaca_script.py", line 385, in <module>
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(Stock_stream, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp' ```

Comment: What does the output of `print(websocket.__file__)` show? (added just below `import websocket`)

Comment: it says 'none'. I have pip installed 'websocket-client' and made sure there is no 'websocket' installed in the command. - I've tried 'import websocket-client' but pycharm underlines it in red

Comment: Your trace is somewhat confusing, you seem to have a circular import thing going on with the scripts `calculatedTime4Real` and `Alpaca_script.py`. In addition, line 6 from `Alpaca_script.py` seems to be missing from your example code. What happens if you run *just* your example code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217541/discussion-between-l-grozinger-and-andrew-english).

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you are using the incorrect library. Erase the current "websocket" library and in the terminal type "pip install websocket-client". This should solve your problems.